# NGINX load balancing - persistance udp upstream (ipsec)

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, ipsec

I'm trying to configure IPSec load-balancer using NGINX plus. 
I configured the policies as described here:

```
stream {

upstream stream_backend {
    server 172.16.255.212:4500;
    server 172.16.255.224:4500;
    server 172.16.254.220:4500;
}

upstream stream_auth_backend {
    server 172.16.255.212:500;
    server 172.16.255.224:500;
    server 172.16.255.220:500;
}

server {
    listen 4500 udp;
    status_zone udp_server;
    proxy_pass stream_backend;
}

server {
    listen 500 udp;
    status_zone udp_auth_server;
    proxy_pass stream_auth_backend;
}
}
```

The problem, IPSec using port 500 for iKEV auth process (handshake), and 4500 for communicate. Because the session isn't persistent, the user starts auth process with one server, and after succeed, the next request proxied to other server, instead the original, because the load balancer.

How can I configure the policies, so the user will stays on the same server, with different ports?

Thanks

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/blog/announcing-udp-load-balancing/#comment-2696072599 maybe nginx just not the right tool for it

Comment: You could try http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_upstream_module.html#hash though

Comment: I tried the hash, using:
hash $remote_addr consistent;

Not worked so far

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? My client currently does not appear to be getting a response from the ipsec server. I'm interested to hear if you were successful.

Comment: Sorry but no, I had migrated to OpenVPN instead.